# How to use Django to search database and display info in web application?

Tags: javascript, python, html, mysql, django

I'm currently working on a data visualization board.
[Cyber Security Data Visualization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Bjgd.png)
I know a few things about creating classes in models.py, objects in views.py, and putting the value of objects in an HTML file.

But the best fuzzy search I know is like this:

`isc_2022 = Isc.objects.filter(issue_date__startswith='2022').count()`

This only gets a count number, but now I want to put information in HTML file through Django. The information is specially selected and ordered like this:
[Search MySQL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KVY30.png)

It is not hard for Python to get a list from a database, here is how I do it:

```
import pymysql

connection = pymysql.connect(
    host="localhost",
    user='root',
    password='xxxxxx',
    database='project', )
cursor = connection.cursor()

cursor.execute("""SELECT company, COUNT(*) AS count 
FROM cc_statistic
GROUP BY company
ORDER BY count DESC
LIMIT 5;""")

myresult = cursor.fetchall()

mylist = []
for x in myresult:
  mylist.append(x)

print(mylist)
```

But how can Django do this and dynamically connect the values with my web application?
And more importantly, is there any better way than asking on Stack Overflow to obtain knowledge like this? I find the official document for Django, like other documentation for other libraries, not easy to use. And they don't always have the thing I want.

Thank you for spending time helping me. Wish us all the best, mate.
: )

Comment: You can execute raw SQL like this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly

Comment: It is more complicated than that, the value needs to be transferred into an HTML file like {{ value }} in {name: 'EAL3', value: {{ value }}},. It has to be a class in model.py and an object in views.py.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for getting the data from your backend to your front-end, you can do something like this:

```
#models.py
class Mydata(models.Model):
    some_field = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    some_second_field = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    some_third_field = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='none') # default is optional

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.id}: {self.some_field}" 
        # this is how the record will be displayed in your admin portal 
        #(if you have it set up in your admin.py)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("mydata_detail", kwargs={"pk": self.pk})
```

```
#admin.py

from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Mydata

# Register your models here.
admin.site.register(Mydata)
```

```
#assuming you've setup your urls.py in your project correctly
#urls.py (from your app *not* your project!)

from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index')
]
```

```
#views.py
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Mydata

def index(request):
    collected_data = Mydata.objects.raw("SELECT * FROM yourappfoldernamehere_mydata")
    context = {
        'data': collected_data,
    }
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

```
#index.html

{% for row in data %}
    {{row.id}}
    {{row.some_field}}  
    {{row.some_second_field}}  
    {{row.some_third_field}}   
{% endfor %}
```

This is all some very basic stuff on getting your database values to the front page.

To get started on learning (without the Django documentation page), you can visit things like: https://www.w3schools.com/django/django_getstarted.php which will show you a step-by-step guide to creating a CRUD page. (which also includes getting database values to the front-end)

Another way to learn fast is by getting books.

I would recommend Django for Beginners, Django for API's and DJango for Professionals (all by William S. Vincent)
https://wsvincent.com/books/

In Django for Beginners you will also find a tutorial on deploying to Heroku, which will be outdated as per November 28, 2022.

Another great way to learn, with any programming language, is by doing!
Think of a fun project to start with (which may be useful), something like a blog with image upload capabilty and some permissions for different roles perhaps?